# Upload File (FormData) to WebApi

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file to an WebApi, but I'm not receiving the file. Also I don't know If the file is being appended. I'm doing this:

```
if (this.state.file) {
            var file = this.state.file;
            if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append("file", file);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/api/service/upload",
                    contentType: "text/csv",
                    processData: false,
                    data: data,
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                        var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
                        if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                            err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Also, to check the content of my Request Payload, I tried this, instead of the Ajax call:

```
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
                xhr.open('POST', '/', true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
                xhr.send(data);
```

And only appears:

> ------WebKitFormBoundary6xZnDkSOxBAxaovA Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Teste.csv" Content-Type:
>   application/vnd.ms-excel
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundary6xZnDkSOxBAxaovA--

Comment: Try removing the `contentType` option from ajax call. And also, please verify `this.state.file` is a file object not an array of file objects. `console.log` it.

Comment: I get this (I guess is a file object):
File {name: "Teste.csv", lastModified: 1491903259490, lastModifiedDate: Tue Apr 11 2017 10:34:19 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 32…}
lastModified
:
1491903259490
lastModifiedDate
:
Tue Apr 11 2017 10:34:19 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
name
:
"Teste.csv"
size
:
32
type
:
"application/vnd.ms-excel"
webkitRelativePath
:
""
__proto__
:
File

Comment: But after I append the file to FormData object, the object only have the prototype, is that normal? Shouldn't have a File object inside?

Comment: That is perfectly normal. I am preparing an answer for this post with some code. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

If the file size is not large, you can use base64 encoding. Send the encoded string data to web api service. Decode and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you have a file object, and it looks right. Give the below code a try.

```
var file; // Assuming this is the file object.
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/api/service/upload',
    data : formData,
    dataType : 'json', // json, html whatever you like.
    contentType: false, // Change this line
    processData: false
}).done(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
}).fail(function(res) {
    console.log(res.responseText);
});
```

If you are using PHP in the api service. You should be able to use `print_r($_FILES)` and see the file there.

Hope this helps.